# Chocolatey package Nartac IIS Crypto 3.0 is no longer installing from the cli

Tags: chocolatey

Our automated scripts have been installing this package for sometime without any issues. We also had this problem last week with the azcopy package (same error) - it was failing for around 4 days and then miraculously started working again. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Installing the package using:
`choco install iiscrypto`

It seems that installing the choco package iiscrypto-cli 3.1 package is currently failing with the error message:

"ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://www.nartac.com/Downloads/IISCrypto/IISCrypto40.exe'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that file has been moved (or removed) by the owner of the software site it's being downloaded from. This is causing the package installation to fail when it attempts to download one of the files, not a problem with Chocolatey CLI itself.

The package is outdated, as well, but in this case the problem is the second file that is being downloaded which no longer exists.

I notice that someone-who-is-probably-you has left a comment on the Disqus feed for that package. I would suggest additionally, either:

- Going to `Possible Package Source` and PRing the updated links into the package or
- Going to the `Possible Package Source` and leaving an issue mentioning that the package is broken or
- Hitting the `Contact Maintainers` button and reporting that the package is broken

[image: Sidebar of Chocolatey Community Repository Package View]

You can probably find updated links by clicking the `Software Site` button, finding it's also outdated, and then going to the root of the site - `nartac.com`, which does still exist.

Answer (score 1):

creator of IIS Crypto here. The link in the package has been wrong for years. We used to have a .Net 2.0 version but that was removed quite awhile ago. The Chocolaty package tries to download both executables, however, they both have linked to the same file for quite a while. We recently removed the redirect (IISCrypto40.exe) as part of a site clean up.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your post. I'm wondering if your comment means that you will continue to support the chocolatey package or if you are saying we should move to a direct download from the site to obtain the fantastic tool that you've created?

Comment: @Nip My understanding based on this is that Jeff doesn't own the package, currently. 
@Jeff If you would like to own the package, we [have a process for requesting access to update it](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/community-repository/users/package-triage-process#i-want-to-take-overhelp-with-package-maintenance-for-my-software). The first step is the `Contact Site Admins` button (shown above).

Comment: James is correct. We do not own or maintain the package. The simple fix would be to remove the second link.

Comment: @Jeff your website https://www.nartac.com has been returning 404 response  for the past couple of days. We can no longer download or install this software. Any ideas what is going on please?